# Page jumps when loading in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

Troubleshooting an issue where the page jumps when it loads in Chrome. Problem does not happen in other browsers. There is a static nav at top, which does not flash or jump, but the banner image and rest of page moves up and down briefly when loaded or re-loaded. There was a FOUC problem which I fixed by moving the css higher within the header. May be related. Any ideas on how to get this jumping to go away completely? I've also tried solutions using JS/CSS outlined here http://www.learningjquery.com/2008/10/1-way-to-avoid-the-flash-of-unstyled-content but no luck.

http://www.mettapartners.org

Comment: Can we get details? Getting your site would be a good start, or if you want, just give us the code. You have to give us something to work with

Comment: http://www.mettapartners.org

Comment: Try moving the js to the bottom of the page. It might be an issue of the JS slowing down the loading

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have done it!

Comment: please accept my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving your `javascript` files to the bottom of the page. This is standard practice- JS at the top of your page will slow the loading down, and can cause errors such as this.

Generally, use this order in HTML:

Stylesheets (CSS)

Content (HTML)

Scripts (JavaScript)

Comment: This best-practice might be all you need for now, but the issue may resurface later (more code, poor network etc.), unless you root-cause and fix the problem.